# Extract which ID appears in consecutive years

Tags: time, conditional-statements, logic, extract, series

i am having troubles trying to extract from my data only the IDs that appear at least on two consecutive years. I couldn't find similar questions for solutions, much sorry if this question it's a duplicate of some sort.
I'll create a data example:

ID= c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 4, 1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 1, 2,6,9,5)
Year= c(2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006,2006, 2007,2007,2007,2007,2007,2007,2007,2007,2008,2008,2008)
DF<- data.frame(ID, Year)

I would like to get a result which shows me which IDs appear in consecutive years only, namely IDs 1,2,3, 4 and 6, as 5 also appears twice, but not consecutively, and the others are unique entries.

Answer (score 0):

Surely there are several ways to do this. One fairly simple way (which assumes the years are already sorted as in your data example) is to first compute the minimum of the differences of the unique years for each ID:

```
mdu = aggregate(Year~ID, DF, function(y) suppressWarnings(min(diff(unique(y)))))
```

This yields (with your data example):

```
  ID Year
1  1    1
2  2    1
3  3    1
4  4    1
5  5    2
6  6    1
7  7  Inf
8  9  Inf
```

(The `suppressWarnings` serves to silence a warning from `min` for an empty `diff` list, coming from IDs only appearing in one year.)

Now, the wanted IDs are those where the minimum year difference is 1 (which means the ID appears in consecutive years); they can be easily extracted by:

```
mdu$ID[mdu$Year==1]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, 
a very handy way to deal with it! Thanks infinitely.